# Updating release def results in error VS402903: The specified value is not convertible to type ReleaseDefinition

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I am updating release definitions using the onpremise Azure DevOps API using the following powershell script:

```
$listurl="https://onpremdomain/{ogr}/{proj}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"

$PAT="Personal access token"

$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

#get the releases' ids.
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

#loop the ids to get each release's definition
foreach($release in $result.value){
 
#get each release's definition
 $definitionurl="https://onpremdomain/{ogr}/{proj}/_apis/release/definitions/$($release.id)?&api-version=6.0"
   
  $releaseDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $definitionurl-Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

  #loop through each stage 
  foreach( $environment in $releaseDefinition.environments){
   
     #loop through each tasks to find the task group
     foreach($task in $environment.deployPhases.workflowTasks){
      
       # change the 'taskId'  to the taskId of your task group
        if($task.taskId -eq "{taskId}"){
           
            $task.version = "2.*"  # update the taskgroup version to the newest version
       }
     }
  }

    $updateurl="https://onpremdomain/{ogr}/{proj}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"
   
    # update the release definition 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -ContentType "application/json" -Method PUT -Body (convertto-json $releaseDefinition -Depth 100)
}
```

When Invoke-RestMethod in the last line is called I get the following error:

```
 Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS402903: The specified value is not convertible to type ReleaseDefinition. Make sure it is convertible to type ReleaseDefinition and 
try again.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement.Data.Exceptions.InvalidRequestException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ReleaseManagement2.Data","typeKey":"InvalidRequestE
xception","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

Any idea why this error occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

REST API doc:

[Get a list of release definitions.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

[Get a release definition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

[Update a release definition.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

Power shell script

```
$listurl="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"
$PAT="{PAT}"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PAT)"))

#get the releases' ids.
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $listurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

write-host $result.value.id

#loop the ids to get each release's definition
foreach($release in $result.value){
 
#get each release's definition
$definitionurl="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/definitions/$($release.id)?api-version=6.0"
#write-host $definitionurl
$releaseDefinition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $definitionurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -Method get

  #loop through each stage 
  foreach( $environment in $releaseDefinition.environments){
   
     #loop through each tasks to find the task group
     foreach($task in $environment.deployPhases.workflowTasks){
     write-host $task.taskId 
       # change the 'taskId'  to the taskId of your task group
        if($task.taskId -eq "e213ff0f-5d5c-4791-802d-52ea3e7be1f1"){
            write-host $task.version
            $task.version = "1.*"  # update the taskgroup version to the newest version
            write-host $task.version
       }
     }
  }
    $updateurl="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{project name}/_apis/release/definitions?api-version=6.0"
   
    # update the release definition 
    Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateurl -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo} -ContentType "application/json" -Method PUT -Body (convertto-json $releaseDefinition -Depth 100)
}
```

[image]

**Update**

I found the issue, the second `Invoke-RestMethod` method is missing the **space** before the `-Headers` parameter, and the issue should be `Invoke-RestMethod : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Collections.Hashtable'.`

[image]

After adding a space before the parameter, it works, you could check the pic below.

[image]

Comment: thanks! But I am still getting the same error even for release definitions that have not been updated

Comment: Hi @doorman, I have updated my answer, please check it and then kindly share the result here. If the issue still occurs, do you mind share a screenshot here? Such as above. Thanks

Comment: Hi @doorman, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT thanks for your help, I was still getting the same error so I decided to update it manually for now. It feels a bit of a hack to use the API and I feel it might make unexpected changes to the releases. So I updated all my releases to version 2 task group in each environment. I like the easy way of editing task groups using the draft->preview->publish method but it lacks support for publishing latest version to multiple releases. We will probably just update the same version instead until multi update feature is supported in the DevOps UI.

Comment: Hi @doorman, Are you using Azure DevOps Server or Azure DevOps Service? In addition, if you just change the 'taskId'  to the taskId of your task group and do not update the release definition, it will works, right?

Comment: By the way, could you please update the rest API version to 5.0 and then try it again?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I am using Azure DevOps Server on premise (v18.170.30525.1) how can I update only the API? I didn´t change any property in the release definition just ran update on it so it didn´t work either.

Comment: Hi @doorman, I found this issue and I have updated the answer, you could check the update, it should work, please check it and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @doorman, How about the issue? Does the answer resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: Hi thanks for your help but I am still getting the same error. I am sorry but I won´t spend more time on this since I already updated the release definitions manually.